# What is the name for the third-order tensor of third-order partial derivatives?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, matrix-calculus

Given a sufficiently nice function $$f:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow\mathbb R$$ one can define a first-order tensor of all first-order partial derivatives in the standard way to obtain the **gradient**, and the same kind of idea allows one to construct a second-order tensor of all second-order partial derivatives to obtain the **Hessian**.

Is there a name for the analogously obtained third-order tensor of **third-order partial derivatives**? I'm writing a bit of code that uses that object to compute the Hessian of a matrix's eigenvalues with respect to some other voodoo that's probably irrelevant to this question, and if there is a standard nomenclature I'd prefer to use it.

Comment: It's the "Tressian" of course. Come on, everybody knows this. Ok, actually, as far as I've ever seen it remains nameless. You can surf the many questions which have been asked about this beast, there are many.

Comment: If you start feeling a bit frustrated with the code, you could still call it the ‘jerk tensor.’

Comment: @JamesS.Cook That was my impression, but I thought I'd ask. There was one question that had a confident answer stowed away in a dead link, and wishful thinking has probably gotten the better of me.

Comment: @giobrach Haha, I like that. If nobody else comes up with the name, the Jerk is just punny enough for my liking.

Comment: Somebody should make a movie.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook it would start slow but towards the middle it'd get tensor

Comment: @Omnomnomnom so the interesting plot point is either a quotient or a multilinear map depending on the director? (I tried, but, honestly I cannot reach the level of your comment)

Comment: If you want some more obscure terminology, I think it can be thought of as something like a section of some $3$-jet bundle. I'm not familiar with this formalism, though.

Comment: I've never seen that object named. A tradition/convention that complicates things is that of using $\nabla\cdot \nabla$ as an abbreviation for the Laplacian, ... which tends to make writing (the completely reasonable) $\nabla\circ\nabla$ for the Hessian too likely to be easily misunderstood. Much less your object $\nabla\circ\nabla\circ\nabla$. "Don't get me started..." :)

Answer (score 3):

Based on the relative silence here at MSE and my inability to find an answer online or at my local university, I'm going to go out on a limb and say that this tensor does not have a standard name.

In my own work, I've simply adopted the nomenclature of $d_0$ for the original function, $d_1$ for its gradient, $d_2$ for the Hessian, $d_3$ for this nonsense, and so on. Strictly speaking, I'm working with maps to $\mathbb R^m$, and each of these tensors is one order higher (e.g. Jacobian rather than gradient)

As somewhat of an aside, if anyone else stumbles across this answer looking for information about what I'm calling $d_3$, as a practical matter one can get often away with an approximation to the product $d_3T$ for an arbitrary tensor $T$, or even just $d_3v$ for an arbitrary vector $v$. There are more complicated schemes that control rounding error better, but one can use the following identity to save on the computation of $d_3$:
$$d_3(x)v\approx\frac{d_2(x+rv)-d_2(x)}r.$$
Simply choose $r$ small enough for the identity to approximately hold and large enough to control rounding error. In the limit they aren't necessarily quite the same, but in practice the following scheme is nearly as simple to implement and controls rounding error better:
$$d_3(x)v\approx\frac{d_2(x+rv)-d_2(x-rv)}{2r}.$$
Since $d_3$ typically dwarfs $d_2$ in total number of elements, this represents a significant savings in time at the cost of a hopefully small amount of approximation error.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, we have the Jacobian, Hessian, etc. But for the third order, we have the **Ramian** matrix.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding any other uses of that phrasing. Do you happen to have any papers, books, or other resources you could recommend?